# Socket.io connection doesn't work for multiple fragments

Tags: java, android, socket.io

I am creating a project with socket.io. It works really fine as long as there is just one fragment. However as I add more fragments in main activity, it starts creating multiple connections, which i think is not a good idea.

At first I connected to socket.io directly from fragments but that was creating one connection for each fragment. So I created a connection in Application class and used that in fragments which instantly solved multiple connection problem. But now a new problem has occurred.

In case of internet disconnection and reconnection, fragment doesn't get reestablished connection from Application class. I have been trying for over a week but no solution. strange thing is, i searched on internet and stackoverflow but not a single such question is ever asked.

here is connection code in Application class

```
synchronized public Socket getSocket() {
    if (mSocket == null) {
        try {
            IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
            opts.reconnection = true;
            opts.reconnectionDelay = 1000;
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://ddbharti.in", opts);

            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "EVENT_CONNECT");
                }

            }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "EVENT_DISCONNECT");
                }
            }).on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error");
                }
            });
            mSocket.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return mSocket;
}
```

and this is how each fragment is connecting

```
socket = application.getSocket();
socket.emit("tag", tag);
```

If internet is working fine, this setup works flawlessly, loads in 300 milliseconds. However as i disconnect/reconnect internet or I keep internet disconnected and start the app and then connect to internet. Connection in Application class connects quickly, but due to some reason connection in current fragment just doesn't get it.

If i switch fragments then it starts listening to connection from Application class again.

So am i missing something here? How can i force fragment to get connection from application class again in case of reconnection without reloading whole fragment?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you put the socket managment in the Application class? Also, why does the fragment have to call the getSocket method? It would be better if you would write a manager class which has a single socket, and write read etc method, trust it will be better.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I created an event listener which keeps telling connection state to fragments and everything is working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of Manager class with socket connection.

Comment: Yes I can, but you told in your answer, that you've solved the issue.

Comment: I think i have solved it but I am always open to suggestions. :)

Comment: Then this is not the topic of this question

Comment: I mean, can you show me how can I create a manager to achieve this. I know how to use it by Application class and I can also use it in a service. But sadly I didin't find any tutorial which teaches to create socket manager class. Can you show an example please?

Comment: Create a new question for this

Comment: @AbhinavSrivastava hey i was facing same issue can u post the working sample code on git hub, so that people with similar problem can solve it by understanging ur code

Comment: Sure, will do that and update that here soon.

Answer (score 0):

So i created an event listner to listen to socket connection status and show ui accordingly. Just one connect with event listner was all that was needed.